# Adopt OpenJDK 11 support for running programs built with POI 3.15 and oracle JDK1.8

Tags: apache-poi, adoptopenjdk

I have some queries on compatibility:

1. We intend to compile \ build our code with Oracle JDK 1.8 on a development machine.  However, the client machine shall have Adopt OpenJDK 11.0.7 where these programs are intended to run.  Is this combination supported - can we run our programs with Adopt OpenJDK?
2. Is POI 3.9 and 3.15 compatible with MS Excel 2019?

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of Apache POI, which have known bugs and security issues? Why haven't you upgraded to the latest supported versions?

Comment: There are some existing programs which are using these versions of POI.  Upgrading these customizations may take some time and hence wanted to check the compatibility with MSO 2019.

Comment: [Apache POI 3.9 was released in 2012](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.9), [Apache POI 3.15 was released in in 2016](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.15), so it's impossible for either to have any 2019 features!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do not intend to use any new features of 2019.  We have some existing template (xlsx) files with all required formatting, which we use to create new files with some additional data into it.  Can we just Open and Save these templates in 2019 (without making any modifications) and use with 3.9 or 3.15?